# Delete audio file causing corrupted file-Weird behavior

Tags: android, file, android-listview, android-mediaplayer, delete-file

I am trying to delete an audio file in my app. When I click on delete, the file gets successfully deleted and the item gets removed from the listview.But when I open the app, the song again appears on the listview even though now its not playable. I tried opening song through stock music app also,it doesn't open. If I check the external storage for its path location, its not found. Where I am I going wrong? Confused...

```
MenuItem miDelete = menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Delete");
            miDelete.setIcon(R.drawable.delete);
            miDelete.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
            miDelete.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                    Iterator<String> it = songAdt.getCheckedItems()
                            .values().iterator();
                    Log.d("sparse boolean", ""
                            + songAdt.getCheckedItems().size());
                    for (int i = 0; i < songAdt.getCheckedItems().size(); i++) {

                        if (it.hasNext()) {

                            int posItem = Integer.parseInt(it.next());
                            Song song = (Song) songView
                                    .getItemAtPosition(posItem);

                            Log.d("file del path", song.getPathId());
                            File file = new File(song.getPathId());

                            files.add(file);
                            positionItem.add(posItem);
                        }

                    }
                    createDialog(files, positionItem);

                    return false;
                }
            });
public void createDialog(final List<File> files2,
        final List<Integer> position) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            getSherlockActivity());

    // set title
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Delete");

    // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Confirm delete the selected track")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < files2.size(); i++) {
                                Log.d("file del path2", "" + files2.get(i));
                                if (files2.get(i).exists()) {
                                    Log.d("file exists", "true");
                                    if (files2.get(i).canWrite()) {
                                        Log.d("file write", "true");
                                        fileDeleted = files2.get(i)
                                                .delete();
                                        Log.d("file deleted??", ""
                                                + fileDeleted); // returns true
                                    } else {
                                        Log.d("file locked", "true");
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Log.d("file not exist", "true");
                                }

                                if (fileDeleted) {
                                    countDeleted++;

                                      songList.remove((int)position.get(i));
                                    getSherlockActivity().setTitle(
                                            R.string.app_name);

                                      songAdt.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                            }
                            Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity().getBaseContext(),
                                    countDeleted + " tracks Deleted",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            countDeleted = 0;
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity().getBaseContext(),
                            "Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

    // create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    // show it
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

**UPDATE**
This is how I am fetching songs in onCreate.

```
 public ArrayList<Song> getSongList(Context context) {
    // retrieve song info
    ContentResolver musicResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    // Fetch only music and not alarms,notification tones
    String selection = AudioColumns.IS_MUSIC + "!= 0";
    Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, selection,
            null, null);

    if (musicCursor != null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        // get columns
        int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaColumns.TITLE);
        int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(AudioColumns.ALBUM_ID);
        int audioId = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(AudioColumns._ID);
        int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(AudioColumns.ARTIST);
        int column_index = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaColumns.DATA);
        int album_index = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(AudioColumns.ALBUM);
        int duration_index = musicCursor
                .getColumnIndex(AudioColumns.DURATION);
        int size_index = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaColumns.SIZE);
        String pathId = null;

        // add songs to list
        do {
            long albumId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
            if (column_index != -1) {
                pathId = musicCursor.getString(column_index);
            }

            String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
            String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
            String thisAlbum = musicCursor.getString(album_index);
            String thisDuration = musicCursor.getString(duration_index);
            String thisSize = musicCursor.getString(size_index);
            long thisAudioId = musicCursor.getLong(audioId);
            songList.add(new Song(albumId, thisTitle, thisArtist, pathId,
                    thisAlbum, thisDuration, thisSize, thisAudioId));

        } while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
        return songList;

    }
    return null;

}
```

Comment: But how could that be useful . Since in stock music app also the corrupted file shows. So onResume and onCreate can't be at fault i guess.

Comment: did you refresh the stock music app? asked for onCreate or onResume to check how does it show up again. You might want to try to refresh the list of songs you have

Comment: There is no option to refresh the music in stock app . So couldn't.;9

Comment: By music, i meant the songs thst you have and see the change reflects properly in your list of songs--externally, not in your app

Comment: If I uninstall and install app again, the song doesn't appear. And the same with the stock music apps. Any suggestions what could be wrong ?

Comment: I guess if while fetching song, I check for path!=nullString selection = AudioColumns.IS_MUSIC + "!= 0" + MediaColumns.DATA + "!= 0"; // this gives error
  Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, selection,
    null, null); it might help.

Comment: The above solution didnt work . Same corrupted file :(

Comment: Any suggestions please?